# Prove $X$ is well ordered.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

Let $(X,\le)$ be a totally ordered set where $X$ is infinite. Given any countable subset of $X$ is well ordered, prove $(X,\le)$ is well ordered as well. It would really help me to know how accurate I am and how valid my arguments are, so that I can know how to improve them and still keep my way of arguing.

$Attempt:$ $\le$ is a total order. Therefore, every subset of $X$ is a chain, naturally. Therefore finite subsets of $X$ are necessarily well ordered, since every two element are comparable and the minimal element is the minimum\lower bound. For infinite subsets it is given as well. Therefore: any subset has a minimum $\land$ every subset is a chain $\Rightarrow$ every chain has a lower bound $\Rightarrow$ there is a minimal element in $X$ by Zorn's lemma. $(X,\le)$ is totally ordered and therefore the minimal element is unique and is comparable with all the elements $\Rightarrow$ $X$ has a least element in the ordering $\Rightarrow$ $X$ is well ordered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This argument has two significant errors. You claim it's given that infinite subsets are well ordered, but this is only given for *countable* subsets; furthermore, you claim to show $X$ is well ordered by showing it has a least element, when you should be showing that *every subset of* $X$ has a least element.

Here's a sketch of a better argument. Take $S\subset X$; we want to show that $S$ has a $\leq$-minimum. Suppose not. Then for any $s_1\in S$ there must be $s_2\in S$ with $s_2<s_1$. Continuing in this way, we get a sequence $s_1>s_2>s_3>...$ in $S$ with no minimum. But this contradicts the hypothesis that countable subsets of $X$ are well ordered.

Comment: I was confused with the definition. Great method, by the way. Thank you.